# Array Index Out Of Bounds

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Index was outside the bounds of the array error occurs when trying to access a website, the first line in code below pops up with the error, and any alteration to it results in more of the same errors to the lines below that. Am I just not using a big enough array or is my code all flustered so I'm running bad numbers?

We Start by scraping pages with a regex expression:

```
                string[] lines = TextBox1.Lines;
                label2.Text = "Custom URL Status: Working";
                this.working.Text = "Fetching Web URL(s)";
                try
                {
                    WebBrowser browser = this.WebBrowser1;
                    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        browser.Navigate(lines[i]);
                        this.BrowserWait(this.WebBrowser1);
                        string[,] parameter = (string[,])this.preg_match(@"([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}[:][0-9]{1,5})", browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
                        if ((parameter[0, 0] == "") | (parameter[0, 0] == null))
                        {
                            this.t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.getFromSite1));
                            this.t.Start();
                            label2.Text = "Custom URL Status: Error";
                            return;
                        }
                        this.t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this._Lambda1));
                        this.t.Start(parameter);
                        browser = null;
                    }
                }
```

This is called:

```
        private void _Lambda1(object a0)
        {
        this.handleList((string[,])a0);
        }
```

Which errors on the first line of this.ToolStrip:

```
        public void handleList(string[,] tmp)
        {
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        this.ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int)Math.Round((double)(Convert.ToDouble(tmp[2, 0]) - 1.0));
        this.ToolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        this.ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;
        int num2 = (int)Math.Round((double)(Convert.ToDouble(tmp[2, 0]) - 1.0));
        for (int i = 0; i <= num2; i++)
        {
            this.ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = i;
            this.proxies.Text = Convert.ToString(this.iWork) + "/" + Convert.ToString(this.iTotal);
            this.iTotal++;
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the relevant declaration (and any intermediate assignments) to `tmp`. Almost surely it's wrong and is the source of the error.

Comment: We need to see how you declare and populate that array. It's too late to start troubleshooting when you overflow the bounds. You need to back up and figure out why the dimensions you're calling out aren't there as you expect.

Comment: You should move the declaration of `num2` up to before you set the `ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum`, as they appear to be the same value. Without the `tmp` declaration however there's not much I can help with.

Comment: For sure `tmp` array don't have 3 rows and hence it's erroring. 
Can you mention the array declaration part.

Comment: As my predecessors said, please provide information of the declaration of `tmp`.

Comment: The function called lambda is amusing.

Comment: You have a blind faith in preg_match returning at least 3 rows. And it doesn't (always). But the real problem is not in preg_match but in the complete lack of validations in that long complicated chain the results are pushed into.

Answer (score 0):

You make sure `parameter[0, 0]` is not `null` or empty, so why don't you check if `parameter[2, 0]` is assigned there as well?

Seeing the contents of the variable is as easy as a breakpoint or a line in the log file.